# Is it possible to process and query mondrian cubes without deploying to pentaho bi-server?

Tags: mdx, olap, pentaho, mondrian, olap4j

If yes, please give a reference. I did a little googling with no result.
I want to use olap4j to query the cubes and use the result in a web application. But, I don't need any of the features of bi-server.
According to tutorials, the olap schemas have to be published on an instance of bi-server. So isn't it really possible to have cubes built, processed and queried independently?

Comment: Try a pure javascript pivot table component at [webpivottable](http://webpivottable.com) . Here is the [demo](http://webpivottable.com/demo) . No plugin, no back end dependence. It connect to XMLA service directly and have MDX mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olap4j is the main programming API for Mondrian. You do not need a Pentaho BI server to use Mondrian. You should read [this tutorial](http://olap4j-demo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/Olap4j_Introduction_An_end_user_perspective.pdf) to get you started.

Comment: Hi @Luc the link is no more available dear, can you please update it

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Saiku - this will handle the server side of mondrian for you and is built from the ground up for integration, so may be easier than using olap4j directly ( saiku itself uses olap4j of course)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you just want to use API functions of mondrian.jar in java class or servlet, instead of via JSP page?

Answer (score 1):

You can deploy the .xml file in tomcat server or saiku server and run it.